# twitter-bootstrap-rails not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am working on ROR app, the app is working fine on local host but when on heroku "http://niveshi.herokuapp.com/portfolio/create" bootstrap is not working and even javascript code is not working. This is my gem file :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

gem "mongoid", "~> 3.1.0"

  # Gems used only for assets and not required
  # in production environments by default.
  group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'less-rails'


 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end

 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'
 gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'

  gem 'mechanize'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

Any guesses where I am wrong.

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20708011/2949565 worked for me, while i tried to push the sample app from railstutorial.org to heroku and the bootstrap was missing. I think that heroku want's the assets to be precompiled and this is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done , actually this should be out of assets

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'less-rails'
```

Answer (score 17):

Use this on production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

If it is not work Then do the following things. 
`rake assets:precompile` it will generate assets file in your public folder, commit all those file then push the code into heroku server.

Answer (score 4):

Try `rake assets:precompile` and then upload again to Heroku.

Comment: did you check this part of the documentation? https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem fixed with adding
a. `gem 'rails_12factor'`
b. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`